# set flag before connection start

Tags: ios, objective-c

in viewDidLoad I want to call webservice for several times.
So my code in viewDidLoad is as follows

```
//Webservice call for industry list
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@index.php/industry/industrylist",baseurl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[@"emailid=b@b.com&password=1234" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
//set flag for industryList
flag = @"industry";
[connection start];

//Webservice call for function list
NSURL *bUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@index.php/functionmdl/allFunctionlist",baseurl]];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestb = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:bUrl
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[requestb setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[requestb setHTTPBody:[@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connectionb = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestb delegate:self];
//set flag for industryList
flag = @"functionmdl";
[connectionb start];
```

But the value of `flag` is always set to `functionmdl` because i have assigned the flag with the string at the just previous line of the last line in the above code. I know that i am setting the flag in wrong way. So, please let me know how can i set flag here. Basically i want to use these flag in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method.
i have to differentiate the webservice response data according to webservice call.
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `connection.currentRequest.URL` to distinguish the request.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *strUrl = [connection.currentRequest.URL absoluteString] ;
    // compare to the url of your request to distinguish them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches here (none involve a flag).

The easiest is typically to use `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]`. Then you can put your `connectionDidFinishLoading` code right here, specific to each request.

That doesn't work if you need more advanced features of `NSURLConnectionDelegate` (like responding to authentication requests). In that case, I usually recommend that you wrap up the connection and delegate into a separate object, and instantiate one for each connection. That way each object is only delegate for a single connection.

In a small number of cases, this still isn't appropriate, and in those cases you can check the connection's request in the delegate (`connection.currentRequest`) to determine which one you're being called about. In some cases, I've created a mutable dictionary property mapping `NSURLRequest` information to some other piece of metadata I wanted in the handlers.

And in the most fancy (and therefore least-often used) case, you can attach metadata (such as an identifier) to your connection using `objc_setAssociatedObject`, but this is seldom necessary.

But I'd look at `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]`. It's the simplest to use and addresses the most common cases easily.